# loop a pressed key at interval

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have an HTML page that calls some local JavaScript files which do many functions. One of the `.js` files has a function for when the key "t" is pressed.

Whenever the user would press the letter "t" then the data on the HTML page will get refreshed. Except I don't want the users to have to press "t". I just want the page to assume that they are pressing it every 2 seconds.

---

Here's what I have right now and it's not working:

```
do {
    $(function() {
        var e = $.Event('GameMoves');
        e.which = 116; // Character 't'
        $('item').trigger(e);
        setInterval(e, 2000);
        x = 1;
    } while (x == 1);
});
```

Here the ASCII code for "t" is 116.

Comment: Can you please add your code.

Comment: I don't have any code. That's what I'm asking for. I need code that keeps pressing 't' for the user every 2 seconds. There's a large .js file and somewhere in there is a function that when the letter 't' is pressed then it will do something...I think refreshPgnSource(); but I'm not really sure since I don't really understand java script :-( I believe when 't' is pressed it calls a refreshPgnSource(); function.

Comment: This isn't a place that will do the work for you, please see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok. Here's what I have right now and it's not working:

do {
  $(function() {
    var e = $.Event('GameMoves');
    e.which = 116; // Character 't'
    $('item').trigger(e);
 setInterval(e, 2000);
 x = 1;
}   
while (x == 1);
}); Here the ascii code for 't' is 116

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like is that you want to page to refresh every two seconds.

If thats the case, try adding this to the `<head></head>` of the page.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">`

**EDIT**
Ok, I think I got it.

In the `setInterval` function, you can try `window.location.reload(false);`

> var i = setInterval(function(){
>       window,location.reload(false); }, 2000);

Comment: Not really. If I wanted the page to refresh I would press F5. In this case the page doesn't refresh, but certain data on the page does get refreshed when the letter 't' is pressed by the user. I just need the page to assume the user has pressed the letter 't' which is a shortcut for a certain function such as refreshing some prices on the page.

Comment: That is not what the question is saying. The answer is a good solution as per the question is concerned.

Comment: The question is simple. What code is necessary to put in an HTML page that will assume the key 't' has been pressed? On this html page if I press the key 't' it automatically updates the price on the page. It doesn't refresh the entire page and reload all the data again.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean something like this? do {
  $(function() {
    var e = $.Event('Press the t key');
    e.which = 116; // Character 't'
    $('item').trigger(e);
 setInterval(e, 1000);
 window.location.reload(false);
 var i = setInterval(function(){ window,location.reload(false); }, 2000);
 x = 1;
}   
while (x == 1);
});

Comment: @DFord where is `keydown == t` (this is pseudo code) that OP asked for?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question that works:

```
var i = setInterval(function(){
    //do your thing
}, 2000);
</script>
```